# TransactionResult.Success does not update my mutableData (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have copied the code from [Save Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data).

which is like this:

```
void addScoreToLeaders(string name, int score ,string 
    key,Dictionary<string,object> childUpdates){    
    reference.Child ("leaders").KeepSynced (true);
    reference.Child ("leaders").RunTransaction(mutableData =>{
        List<Dictionary<string,object>> leaders = mutableData.Value as 
                             List<Dictionary<string,object>>;
            if(leaders == null){
                leaders = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
            } else if(mutableData.ChildrenCount >= MAX_SCORE){
                int minScore = int.MaxValue;
                Dictionary<string,object> minValue = null;
                foreach(var child in leaders){
                    if(!(child is Dictionary<string,object>)) continue;
                    int childScore = (int)((Dictionary<string,object>)child)
                        ["score"];
                    if(childScore < minScore){
                        minScore = childScore;
                        minValue = child;
                    }
                }
                if(minScore > score){
                    return TransactionResult.Abort ();
                }

                leaders.Remove (minValue);              
            }

            //Add the new high score
            Dictionary<string ,object> newScoreMap = new 
            Dictionary<string,object> ();
            LeaderBoardEntry entry = new LeaderBoardEntry (name, score);
            newScoreMap = entry.ToDictionary ();
            leaders.Add (newScoreMap);
            mutableData.Value = leaders;
            return TransactionResult.Success (mutableData);
        });
    }
```

okay, there's two things not happens correctly :

- TransactionResult.Success(mutableData) does not store the new data at the location
- Return mutableData null for every first time i call the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] after examining the code and several attempts of testing found the solution .

line number five (5) of the code causing problem which is :

```
List<Dictionary<string,object>> leaders = mutableData.Value as 
                         List<Dictionary<string,object>>;
```

replace with :

```
Dictionary<string,object> leaders = mutableData.Value as 
                         Dictionary<string,object>;
```

because **mutableData.Value** returned the data contained in this instance as native types, and i saved the data like **Dictionary<.string,object>;**